# How to return void methods in Java?

Tags: java, methods, return

I am really struggling to find how to do a class assignment. I'm supposed to use this statement:

```
public static void getExamData(char responses[])
```

in order to get exam data on 20 answered questions. However, I'm confused because you can't return values in void methods? How am I going to get this data back to main?

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hwk11 {
public static void main(String args[])
{

    final int PASSING_SCORE = 15;
    char[] answerKey = 
    { 
        'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C',
        'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B',
        'D', 'A' };     
    }
    //more code here that uses the responses[] array to do more things like display info
}

public static void getExamData(char responses[])
{
    for(int index = 0; index < 20; index++)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter " + index + ": ");
        responses[index] = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Putting the values into the array in the `getExamData` method will allow them to be exposed to the calling method.  You can't change the reference that `responses` points to, but you can change it's content

Comment: Or change the return type from `void` to something that allows you to return values.  `int[]` perhaps, or `ExamData`.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass array reference to `public static void getExamData(char responses[])`, any modification made to the array will be saved.

So you will have your response in the array after your function executed.

Note that when you declare `char[] response = new char[]`, the variable `response` does not actually store the array content but it stores the reference to the array.

When you modify, for example `response[0]` you're modifying the array content, but the array reference (`response` variable) is not changed.

Hence after the function executed, you can use your `response` variable to access the modified array content.

Comment: what parameter would I use for char[] response = new char[] though?

Comment: It depends. Your exam response data consist of 20 answer so you should initialize it with 20.